# Django do not return newest content in homepage views with lots of extra_context

Tags: django, django-views

I built my Django homepage's view using direct_to_template plus lots of extra_context, code example:

```
extra_context = {
    'photo': Photo.objects.filter(section='example')[:5],
    'video': Video.objects.filter(section='example')[:5],
    'post': Post.objects.filter(section='example')[:5],
    'page': Page.objects.get(slug='example'),
    'artists': Artist.objects.all(),
    }


url(r'^$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'homepage.html', 'extra_context': extra_context}, name='homepage')
```

But content in homepage always not the newest, I have to restart dev server or gunicorn in production to make it diaplay newest content. Where does the problem lie in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your content is evaluated only once: when `urls.py` is imported. I think you need a normal view here. Or you can pass callables (or other lazy objects) to context, not evaluated ones.

Comment: Thank you, althought I solve my problem using render import from django.shortcuts in views, you're correct.